# How to use optionKey and optionValue on g:select when passing a map

Tags: grails, select, gsp

I have a list of key value pairs in my controller,

```
List Instances= [
    'xxxxx':'yyyyy',
    'aaaaa':'bbbbb','
]
[Instances:Instances]
```

and in my gsp

```
<g:select name = "sInstance" from="${Instances}" optionKey="key" optionValue ="value" />
```

but the resulting error is

> Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag : Error
>   executing tag : No such property: key for class:
>   java.lang.String

I'm looking for:

```
<option: value='xxxxx'> yyyyy
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid list really. It looks like a map. Did you intend it to be a list of maps?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore yes I plan on it being a list of maps, where the option value will be the key and the text will be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 4):

Like Joshua Moore mentioned, you are actually passing a map, not a list.  You should either fix this in the controller, or you can just call `.entrySet()` from your tag:

```
    <g:select name="sInstance" from="${Instances.entrySet()}" 
        optionKey="key" optionValue="value" />
```